# Open mat-expansion-panel ONLY when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Is there a way in which I can make my mat-expansion-panel open **ONLY WHEN** I click a certain button?

I am thinking of having a list of info that I can click an edit icon on, which would cause the expansion to happen revealing the edit options...

Of course, I do not want the panel to expand when clicking randomly on the row, but only on the edit icon...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to add to your styles.css file the following code:

```
span.mat-expansion-indicator
{
   pointer-events: visiblefill !important; 
}

mat-expansion-panel-header 
{
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Great! Works perefect! You genius!!

Comment: Thanks! It works, however it makes everything inside unclickable unless whitelisted with `visiblefill`. Do you know a way to let everything descending the `mat-expansion-panel-header` still clickable? Something like `*:not(mat-expansion-panel-header)` (not working).

Answer (score 0):

#HTML CODE:

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="panelOpenState">

<mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
        Edit
    </mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
<p>Edit Body</p>
</mat-expansion-panel>

<button (click)="togglePanel()">Edit</button>
```

#TS CODE:

```
panelOpenState: boolean = false;

togglePanel() {
this.panelOpenState = !this.panelOpenState
}
```

Comment: This adds an additional button to toggle - it doesn't make it _open ONLY WHEN_ clicking a certain button.